# What is an Orientation Distribution Function (ODF) and what does it represent in diffusion-MRI?

Tags: reference-request, spherical-harmonics

I am reading up on Diffusion MRI where there is discussion on Orientation Distribution Function (ODF), to represent the angular aspect of diffusion probability by a spherical ODF.

Can anyone please give me a basic introduction on Spherical Orientation Distribution Functions and its role in studying diffusion MRI.

Comment: Don't you have some book or course literature to read about it? I think diffusion MRI would be maybe better fit for physics or signal processing sites. If you get any math questions about it then this site is probably good, like vector analysis or tensor calculations. As asked currently it seems more like a question where the answer would be a reference to a course or a textbook, but such answers are rarely suitable for a site like this unless you actually are looking for a reference to a textbook or a course. If that is the case then you can add "reference request" as a tag to the question.

Comment: I have read the basics of MRI and Diffusion MRI from online video tutorials and articles and have grasped it well. However, to understand the underlining Signal processing and maths, I am reading a PhD thesis to quickly catch up on the most basic mathematical concepts. In the thesis, the writer has only briefly mentioned these functions and I wanted a basic explanation on them. Not a detailed derivation or explanation.

Comment: You should not "quickly catch up on the basic concepts". You should learn them thoroughly. What a probability distribution function is is something you read about in a first probability course on bachelor level.